# self.table_name appears to be caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, single-table-inheritance

For various reasons I won't go into here, we need to implement a table-per-customer setup for a couple of our models. For most customers, the default table will be fine. But for some we need to point the model to a different table. The table name is stored in the customer record as custom_table_name. Here's how I tried doing it in Rails (2.3.10):

g rails

In the console, assume customer with id 10 has custom_table_name set to 'big_co_foos'

```
Foo.customer = Customer.find(10)
Foo.table_name 
#outputs "Foo.table_name called"
#then "big_co_foos"
```

Looks good so far, but try calling `Foo.table_name` again

```
Foo.table_name 
#outputs "foos"
```

The table name isn't "sticking." From what I can tell, the call to  `super` in `self.table_name` is the culprit. If I don't call super in that method, the local function is called every time. But I obviously don't won't to re-implement table_name here. I suspect I must be missing something around how class methods inherit vs. instance methods. Any suggestions?

Also, I tried using a class variable instead (@@customer), but that didn't make a difference.

Finally after looking at the Rails source code I tried calling `reset_table_name` instead of `super` but it seemed to have the same result as calling `super` (that is, subsequent calls to `Foo.table_name` are bypassed).

**Update: This appears to be working**

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
    @customer = nil

    def self.customer=(value)
        @customer = value
        if @customer && @customer.table_name
            self.set_table_name(@customer.table_name)
        else
            self.reset_table_name
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: `table_name` is cached in numerous places: it's not intended to change at runtime. Doing so globally is particularly concerning.

It's a little painful, and often this can be done better by either having separate instances of your app, or by creating distinct models (dynamically if needed) for each table. Joins in particular will get extremely dicey if your model is spread across several tables.

Rather than go through all the options, I refer you to this old SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856064/dynamic-table-names-for-active-record-models

Comment: I'd encourage you to go in to the table-per-customer reasons that you don't want to go into, because that's a really nasty problem to solve in rails.  Is this a legacy database issue?  Is the model the same, but you want to pull from a different table?

Comment: It's a scalability issue. Most customers can work on the default setup, but a few will generate millions of rows and we want to be able to move them to a separate table/database/host if necessary. We don't need to be able to aggregate data from these tables across customers.

We're taking a similar approach to New Relic for similar reasons:
http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/7/18/new-relic-architecture-collecting-20-billion-metrics-a-day.html