# set table name dynamically to a rails Model in a multithreaded environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

How to set table name dynamically to a rails (2.3.8) model in a multithreaded app environment ?

For Ex:
Table names can be Table_Name_01, Table_Name_02....etc

Since set_table_name is a class method of ActiveRecord::Base class, if I use that method the table name will be set at the class level which can cause problems in a multithreaded app.

I mean, When I use Model.find, the query execution should dynamically find the correct table based on my logic and use that table for the query execution.

Please help me in this regard. Thanks in advance...

Comment: why you need this? you can look for database sharding https://github.com/bpot/data_fabric

Comment: Thanks for reply @Amar,but actually we will be creating tables and drop them after some period of time. Hence, I want to use the one model to refer those tables dynamically based on some logic. Is it possible to set the table name without causing any problems to other users in a multithreaded app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856064/dynamic-table-names-for-active-record-models?rq=1 does this help?

Comment: I'm looking for an option to set table name to a model based on user attributes. The problem I'm thinking of now is, if I set the table name using one user's attribute, then at the same time, if some other user tries to access that model then incorrect table will be used by that model for the other user. Please help me to avoid this problem. My actual expectation is the Model should be able to use corresponding table based on the user attributes at the same time.